# How I can get ports associated to the application that opened them?

Tags: c++, linux

I need to get a list of all opened ports on my machine and what application opened them.
I need to get this information programmatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hoping a cleverer answer would appear. I did just this (programmatically in Python), in an attempt to rewrite a program called NetHogs. My version [is here](https://github.com/anacrolix/archive/tree/master/projects/nethogs2), specifically [here is the module in Python](https://github.com/anacrolix/archive/blob/master/projects/nethogs2/proctab.py) used to parse the table from `/proc`. If you're not [Python](http://python.org/) literate (go learn it), then take a look at the [original NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/), which uses a blend of C/C++ (and is a bit painful to read hence the rewrite).

It's worth noting that extensive or quickly repeated attempts to parse socket information from `/proc` is very CPU intensive, as the operating system has to handle every syscall made, and parse internal structures dynamically. As such you'll find some caching, and timing assumptions made in the source of both projects I've linked you to.

The short of it is, you need to relate the socket inodes given for each process in `/proc/<pid>/fd` to the connections given in `/proc/net/<proto>`. Again, example parsing, and how to locate all of these are present in both projects.

Comment: Broken links for your rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement the following:

1. socket=`ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd  | grep socket | sed 's/.*socket:\[//' | sed 's/\]//'`
2. grep $socket /proc/net/tcp
3. Parse the output from the previous command (second entry contains port information)

Comment: +1 for putting some meat on the very bare bones of my suggestion. If I was implementing, this would probably be enough information.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec('netstat');
```

Comment: netstat tells you which ports are open, but not which applications opened them. lsof will do that.

Comment: @n0rd: All these years and I didn't know! Thanks a lot for that hint, +1!

Answer (score 0):

The information about open files (including sockets) can be dug out of the `/proc` directory.

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html) gives a lot of detail and gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
ss -nltup 
netstat -ltupn
lsof  -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

Edit: Ah sorry, not programmatic. But helpful if you want to fork a process. 
No point in re-inventing the wheel every time.